# ES6 Import giving undefined for an object

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules

This is a very simple import/export but the import is giving undefined no matter what. I've been following Mozilla's documentation. There's been a number of answers on Stackoverflow, and I've implemented several of the posted solutions, including making the export an object, and a function but nothing is working.

```
const env = "dev"
const content_dev = {
  "artworks" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/arts",
  "projects" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/projects",
  "notes"    : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/notes"
}
const content_prod = {
  "artworks" : "https://bahlalala.com/api/arts",
  "projects" : "https://bahlalala.com/api/projects",
  "notes"    : "https://bahlalala.com/api/notes"
}

const urls = (env == "dev") ? content_dev : content_prod
console.log(urls) // this is fine

export default urls
```

Where I'm doing the import.

```
import urls from "../../urlProvider"

console.log(urls) // undefined
```

Update: ok, so this works on the back-end but I need it to work in the browser. I have got babel and webpack for the SSR react app, but would module exports not work on the front end?

Comment: have you tried `module.exports = { url }` & `import { url } from "../../urlProvider"`?

Comment: Is this example trimmed down? It seems like it probably is. Most likely, the issue is that `urls = (env == "dev") ? content_dev : content_prod` hasn't actually run yet because of a dependency cycle in your module import ordering.

Comment: @loganfsmyth It is trimmed, the context of the use is inside of a SSR react component on the front end, which I'm now thinking is the issue. `urls` object is defined before the export.

Comment: Are there any other `import` lines above `export default urls`? If so, you could have a dependency cycle that causes this.